Wire Size for 100 amp Sub panel? 230 ft
Im running feeders from my main 200 amp panel. To a sub panel that is rated 100 amps about 230 Ft away according to the South Wire Voltage drop calculator and the distance, the minimum size wire for AL would be 3/0 is this correct?
I would think 3/0 is a bit overkill but also the distance is pretty long

There are several key issues to consider that can make a huge difference:
Using the Southwire Voltage Drop Calculator for 100A, 240V aluminum wire and 230 feet, I also get the 3/0 answer. However:

100A panel does not mean 100A current. You might use a 100A panel (quite common) in order to have plenty of spaces for a bunch of small circuits. If your actual expected current usage is, for example, 50A, then the calculation will drop to 2 AWG.
120V vs. 240V. Your calculation is for 240V, which is generally what you want to use if you can because it gets much better results than 120V. On the other hand, if you have a lot of 120V loads then you might actually need to use 120V in the calculation. Switching to 120V and 40A (because if you have a lot of 120V loads then you will probably have low overall current requirements) gets 2/0 AWG. (Yes, 120V @ 40A needs much bigger wire, because of much higher voltage drop, than 240V @ 50A.)
Actual usage is normally capped at 80%. That is a hard rule for "continuous" loads, but can usually be applied in general - if you have a lot of short-term large loads (e.g., welder) they probably won't be all on at the same time. So back to 100A that means at most, even if you really need to provision for 100A due to other requirements, you are at 2/0 rather than 3/0.
Allowable drop. This is the big one. While 3% is an ideal number, most equipment can handle a somewhat larger drop. Consider also that even if you have an expected peak of 80A, most of the time you won't be near that and if a lot of your biggest loads can handle a 5% drop (when all running at the same time) then 5% is a much better number to use. 80A, 240V, 5% = 1 AWG.

So figure out your actual anticipated total load.
If this is a residential building the you should do a proper NEC Load Calculation (Google it).
If it is something simpler - e.g., garage or workshop, then add up everything that might all be used at the same time including lights, tools, etc. If you may have EV charging in the future, be sure to add another 20A or 30A @ 240V to allow for that.
Then use that number in the calculator instead of 100A. And consider whether 4% or 5% is acceptable - it probably is unless you expect to run everything at once on a regular basis.
